# how to append gc log

Tags: java, garbage-collection

below is gc logging option to write the specific file

```
-verbose:gc
-Xloggc:/logs/gc.log
```

OK. Good.
but when java app is restarted, old gc log contents in the file disappeared.
I hope vm to **append** gc log to "/logs/gc.log" file.

does option for this exist? or i have to write shell script to back up old gc file?

Answer (score 5):

You are explicitly requesting that the gc data goes to a file named 'gc.log'.  You can append the **date & pid** to the filename to prevent this sort of collision.  No mechanism within Hotspot exists to prevent the data from being overwritten.